# Can someone clean up these comments?

Tags: support, flagging

Not enough reputation to flag them myself out at least don't see that option.

After typing out "win-win for you print it out and send it to your mom so she can put it in her fridge and marvel at the fine man you turned into" I remembered it's a waste of time taking trolls' bait.

Can someone please remove the exchange between batfinger and myself as it adds no  value to the q&a [What's the easiest way to draw this complex plane in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134397/whats-the-easiest-way-to-draw-this-complex-plane-in-blender/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91251/discussion-on-question-by-kerdos-media-can-someone-clean-up-these-comments).

Answer (score 5):

I removed the comments. No hard feelings I hope. I truly expect batFINGER was trying to help, and not being a troll. Thing is some of us kind of get bothered (myself included) when someone says "I searched everywhere" or "spent days looking for this" etc.
I'm not making excuses for that first comment, it was out of place.

You need [15 reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) (which you now have) to flag. Then it is as simple as clicking the red flag icon on the comment.
[flag a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/278094)

Comment: Thank you. It's really frustrating trying to figure out how to do something simple in a new program that you've done many times in others. I'm grateful to people who volunteer their time and I try to do that myself when I can. When people use terms like that they know what they're asking is simple or basic but for whatever reason they're stuck and they need help. At one point we're all new at something or just have a block and need help. That's what I try to keep in mind when I read things like that.

Comment: You wrote [I'm not making excuses for that first comment, it was out of place].  It seems like you are making excuses when I read the [bothered] word.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger Being bothered and showing it (e.g. by being rude) are two different things. This is further complicated by the ability of different people to have wildly different interpretations of what counts as "being rude". Linking to a search engine is one of those things which may very easily to seem like a tactful reminder to one person, and a blatant passive aggressive troll to another.

Comment: @gandalf3 I read what you wrote twice.  It did not impact me in any way because I do not see the relevance of what you wrote.  Perhaps you can explain it better or we can leave it in its current state.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I meant to show how stating "some of us kind of get bothered" isn't excusing rude behavior (with an addendum to the effect that "rude behavior" is not well defined).

Comment: @gandalf3 I hope what you wrote is useful for someone.  My original comment stands.  Perhaps David can respond.  Are you the appointed spokesman for David?